# Why is my css not being applied to my page?

Tags: css

I recently message boxes that style a message given during a php statement, and they style the message.

This is my php code.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE account SET is_active=1, activation_code='' WHERE activation_code='$code'");
$message_good = '<div class="register_thankyou"><p>Success! Your account has been activated. You may now <a href="login.php">log in</a>.</p></div>';
        } else {
$message_good = '<div class="register_error"><p>Account has already been activated, or you have an invalid activation code.</p></div>';
        }
```

For some reason, it loads the style register_thankyou but not for register_error.

Both styles have this css setup.

```
/* ACTIVATION MESSAGES */
.register_thankyou {
    background-color: #e3f6da;
    border: 1px solid #3b7008;
    padding: 20px;
}
.register_thankyou h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.register_thankyou p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.register_error {
    background-color: #f8e5e4;
    border: 1px solid #c41100;
    padding: 20px;
}
.register_error h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.register_error p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

All thats different is the background and border color

Can someone explain to me why one style is being applied and the other isnt?

Thank you: [image]

error: [image]

it works on here tho: http://jsfiddle.net/q8ozgfmu/

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Thanks il update that, but that isnt what is causing the problem... @Kermit

Comment: There is obviously some issue in the rest of the page/html -- without seeing the code it's impossible to know. Have you checked out the styles in your browser's Inspector / Developer tools to see why they aren't being applied?

Comment: I have no idea why it wouldn't be, all I did was just rename the class on the html page and copy/paste rename the style in style.css @ialarmedalien, I manually dded it directly on my HTML page with **<style> </style>** tags and it worked.

Comment: could you please share your html too ?

Comment: could you try, right clicking the problem element and "inspect element", see what you find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i alarmed alien said, check in the Browser's inspector. The style might be getting overridden. Or the other reason could be that the updated style.css may not have loaded in the browser. Try clearing the cache and load the page again.

Comment: You were spot on! I loaded style.css and refreshed it and it added those lines to it.